# Width limitations with constraints when window resized

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to add a custom view in an nswindow in my osx app.

[image: Page Resize]

I need to give a minimum and maximum width values for the custom view which is located in the centre. The view's width should expand until a certain point (maximum width value) but should stop expanding if user continues to expand the window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results of what you tried and how did that differ from what you expected? Did you put any effort into this at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do all of this with layout constraints.

First, we need to specify where the view should be relative to the window. For the sake of this tutorial, I'm going to assume you want it centered:

[image]

Next, we add our constraint for the minimum width:

[image]

To make this a minimum instead of an absolute width, click on the constraint and change it to "Greater Than or Equal" in the Attributes Inspector:

[image]

Now do the same thing, making another width constraint for the maximum. This time, set it to "Less Than or Equal":

[image]

Now the width constraints are set up. But we're not done. We've now set a minimum and a maximum, but the width is still ambiguous—there is no way for the layout constraint system to decide what exact width between 300 and 700 that it should actually be using at any given point. There are two steps to fix this. First, we need to make sure that the view will be entirely within the window and not run off the edges, so create some Greater Than or Equal constraints making sure it stays within its bounds:

[image]
[image]

(Also, make a trailing constraint which is set up identically).

Finally, we need one last set of constraints; we want some leading and trailing constraints, marked Equal, but with a lower priority:

[image]

(Also add a trailing constraint, identically configured)

What does this one do? Well, it tells us that, unless our other constraints (specifically the maximum width, in our case) make it impossible, we'd like the edges of the view to be the standard distance from the window edge. The reason we use 499 as the priority is because that the value of `NSLayoutConstraint.Priority.windowSizeStayPut` is 500. The documentation has this to say about `.windowSizeStayPut`:

> It's generally not appropriate to make a constraint at exactly this priority. You want to be higher or lower. Constraints with higher priorities can adjust the window’s size. Constraints with lower priorities must be fulfilled using the current window size.

If we set our constraint to higher than 500, the system would restrict us from making the window too wide for these constraints to be valid. That's not what we want, since we want the edge spacing to expand in this case. So since we want to be able to break this constraint by resizing the window, we set it to slightly less than 500—so, 499. This means that the constraint system will try to put the view here, but if it can't do it because we made the window too wide, it will allow this constraint to break, although it'll still try to get as close as it can without breaking the other constraints. So your view will be at its maximum width, and centered in the window.

Voilà!

Comment: This is the best answer I've ever received in Stack overflow. Thank you very much. Adding multiple leading and trailing constraints were the part which I couldn't consider. Cheers.